# iMacro issue posting to minds. com

Tags: imacros

The new social media site minds.com does not seem to have an API for posting, so I have tried to create a macro to do so from a single line text file, thus (iMacros for Firefox [50.1]).  I have tried the x-y method and the conventional methods as well as the "experimental" mode, shown following:

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
'SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE C:\[path-to-file]\[single line of text here].txt
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
'SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
'SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{1}}
URL GOTO=https://www.minds.com/newsfeed
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>MINDS-APP>MINDS-BODY>MINDS-    NEWSFEED>DIV>DIV>MINDS-NEWSFEED-POSTER>DIV>DIV>FORM>TEXTAREA" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>MINDS-APP>MINDS-BODY>MINDS-   NEWSFEED>DIV>DIV>MINDS-NEWSFEED-POSTER>DIV>DIV>FORM>TEXTAREA" CONTENT=Hi!
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>MINDS-APP>MINDS-BODY>MINDS-    NEWSFEED>DIV>DIV>MINDS-NEWSFEED-POSTER>DIV>DIV>FORM>DIV>BUTTON" BUTTON=0
```

and I tried:

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.minds.com/newsfeed
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 30
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:message CONTENT=Hello!
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:Post<SP>send
```

Neither seems to work, nor does an x-y click (which just highlights the 'Post' button but does not "click" it).

The salient HTML for the button is:

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored" type="submit">
Post <i class="material-icons">send</i>
</button>
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

-Brian Brown, Ph.D.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your macro must work fine:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>MINDS-APP>MINDS-BODY>MINDS-NEWSFEED>DIV>DIV>MINDS-NEWSFEED-POSTER>DIV>DIV>FORM>TEXTAREA" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>MINDS-APP>MINDS-BODY>MINDS-NEWSFEED>DIV>DIV>MINDS-NEWSFEED-POSTER>DIV>DIV>FORM>TEXTAREA" CHARS="Hi !"
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>MINDS-APP>MINDS-BODY>MINDS-NEWSFEED>DIV>DIV>MINDS-NEWSFEED-POSTER>DIV>DIV>FORM>DIV>BUTTON" BUTTON=0
```

Doesn't it?

Comment: yes; but it just doesn't downclick the "Post" button.  Thanks!

Comment: Everything works for me. I don't know what's wrong. Try the 3rd line as follows: `TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Post<SP>send`